# (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [400] The VM runtime does not support basic scaling or dynamic backends

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

What I do wrong

I just try to upload my python flask app on google cloud app engine

### With that commands

> gcloud config set project project-85474158
>
> gcloud app deploy

FOLDER STRUCTURE

```
MY_APP
     |
     |__app.yaml
     |__requirements.txt
     |__setup.py
```

### app.yaml

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:setup

runtime_config:
    python_version: 3

api_version: 1
instance_class: B8
basic_scaling:
    max_instances: 2
    idle_timeout: 10m
```

### requirements.txt

```
Flask==0.12.2
gunicorn==19.6.0
```

### setup.py

```
import logging

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return 'Hello Youtube v2'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `env: flex` which means you are trying to use GAE Flexible. There are a few things in your code incompatible with Flexible:

1. You cannot specify `instance_class: B8`. Instance classes are from GAE Standard. Instead, leave it out entirely or specify [resources](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#resource-settings)
2. You cannot specify `basic_scaling`. This is also from Standard. Instead specify [`automatic_scaling` or `manual_scaling`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#services).
3. You are running gunicorn with main:setup, but you are using object app in module setup, so you should use `setup:app`.